# Why does if statement never equal "0" or "1" ? I print variable "line" and it is a "0" or "1". But IF statement never works.

Tags: java, if-statement

```
/**
 * @(#)StringToFile.java
 *
 *
 * @author 
 * @version 1.00 2016/2/14
 */
package StringToFile;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;


public class StringToFile {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

 read("0");
}

public static String read(String msg2) throws IOException {
```

This is hard coded read of text file

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("g:/dungeontreasure/DMJ-solito-v2.12/test.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
for (String line : lines) {
```

msg2 is assigned what was read from text file. I hope.

```
msg2 = line; //  I assign msg2 what was read from file.
```

Now, I print out the contents of the text file. this part works.

```
System.out.println("line read:" + line); // I print out line
```

Now I check if the text file had a "1" in it, but this never works.

```
if (msg2==("1")) {
    System.out.println("check read: " + msg2);  // check to see what we read. But this never works.

        }
```

Now I check if the text file had a "0" in it, but it never works.

```
if (msg2==("0")) {
System.out.println("check read: " + msg2); // check to see what we read. 



        }

}  

return(msg2);
}

}
```

Comment: Not really a duplicate because the problem is not on comparing string using equals or == but on the hidden content of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to compare objects use always the method `.equals()`, not the operator `==`.

Using the operator `==` test for the same object (same location in memory), instead the method `.equals()` check for the same content.

So instead of

```
if (msg2==("1")) {
```

your code should be

```
if (msg2.equals("1")) {
```

Comment: I tried the if (msg2.equals("1")) but it still doesn't work. There must be something else that is wrong.

Comment: Check for the length of your string. Perhaps there are white spaces.

Comment: Yes Davide, you are correct. The text file is being written by another program and it is leaving a few spaces. I don't know why. Is there a way in Java to read only the first character of a text file?

Comment: You can read it and use the trim() function to remove spaces at the beginning and at the end of the string.

Comment: I used msg2.trim(), but the IF statements didn't seem to work. I think mabie I need to just read 1 character from text file. That's all I actually need. Not sure what method to use.

Comment: Actually trimming or read only one char has the same effect in this situation.

Comment: It works! Thank you David. :)